# ElasticSearch Update documents after mapping update

Tags: elasticsearch

Im having an issue after mapping update.
I've added some multi-fields to my document fields with such a request:

```
PUT /user/_mapping/_doc
{
  "properties": {
    "achievements": {
      "type": "nested",
      "properties": {
        "description": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          }
        },
        "name": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But now I'm unable to search using `achievement.name.keyword`.
How do I update my old data to have a new updated mapping and to be searchable with .keyword?

ES version 6.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution. You can update mapping with query and all of the documents (that fulfill query criteria) will be updated with new mapping.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html

Answer (score 0):

**After updating the index mapping, in order to perform a search on `achievement.name.keyword`, you need to reindex the data again in the index.**

Once the data is indexed (based on the new index mapping), you can perform a search on `achievement.name.keyword`.

OR the other way is that you create a new index with the new index mapping, and use the [reindex API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html), to index the data from old index to new index.

```
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "<old-index>"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "<new-index>"
  }
}
```

Comment: @Ydrus please go through the answer, and let me know if this resolves your issue ?

Comment: Hey. Yes it is a valid response although I was hoping for something to rebuild current index without reindexing. But yeah if there is no other way then reindexing it is.

Comment: @Ydrus its been a long time ! Can you please accept and upvote the answer, if it helped you resolve your issue. TIA ;-)

Comment: It did not resolve the issue since reindex does huge spike on resources demand plus it requires double of disk space to be available. This was not a solution. Update by query was a valid solution to my issue.